# Nusoap Undefined index in nusoap.php on line

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to call my WS from my device, but I get this error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in C:\wamp64\www\gcm\lib\nusoap.php on line 6637

But, when I test the WS from SOAPUI I get the correct result:

[image: here]

Any solution?

Comment: check for syntax errors in your code

Comment: no syntax erros as you can see in the image

Comment: as per your statement, that is not an error. it is just a notice, you can ignore that

Comment: But , i get an error from my device , the data are not displayed

Comment: disable php errors by error_reporting(0) and check

Comment: Omg , thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your statement, that is not an error. it is just a notice, you can ignore that.

disable php errors by error_reporting(0) and check